# Unable to open app in android using link web link from other app

Tags: android

```
 <activity android:name=".unusedclasses.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:label="Main Activity">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://mainactivity” -->
                <data android:scheme="example" android:host="mainactivity" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>




         <activity
            android:name=".test.ActivityOne"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:label="Activity One">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/activityone” -->
                <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/activityone" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:label="Activity One">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://activityone” -->
                <data android:scheme="example" android:host="activityone" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is my code  and i am trying to launch app from  other app using URL link but i am unable to open . This is my http://www.example.com/activityone link when i try to open using other app then its redirect to browser and its starting google search while i am trying to open APP .
while when i trying to executing from trminal
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://activityone?movie=SpiderMan" com.exmaple.myapp

then launching but when i try to open using web browser or link i am unable to open please help me what i am doing wrong.